# how to save file to external storage, currently it creates document but it size is 0B

Tags: java, android, scoped-storage

I want to backup my database with new methods,my target sdk is 30, I don't know what i am doing wrong here.
I am passing type to setType but it only creates file with 0B. how can i properly backup database.

What i am currently doing is

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
i.setType("application/x-sqlite3");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, DATABASE_NAME);
startActivity(i);
Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

so how can i store my database with data to external storage when user presses export button

[image]

Comment: `File file3 = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath()+"/F&H/"+DATABASE_NAME);
` You are not using `File f` and hard coding again `F&H`. Better: `File file3 = new File(f, DATABASE_NAME);`

Comment: `if (!f.exists()){
                        f.mkdir();
                    }` Check return value! `if (!f.exists()){
                       if ( ! f.mkdir()) return;
                    }`

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }` Place logstatements in it and a Toast() to inform the user. And a return statement as it does not make sense to continue when there is a catch.

Comment: `+".provider", new File(String.valueOf(getExternalFilesDir("F&H"))+"/"+DATABASE_NAME)` Do not construct a new File instance. Use File file3.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` That would be wrong if there was a catch as said before.

Comment: `i.setDataAndType(uri,"*/*");` Which app should open you database file. Use the appropriate extension for your file and use proper mimetype if you want to let open your database file by external application.

Comment: `I am passing uri to setData but it only creates file with 0B.` ? That will not create a file but assumes that there is a file.

Comment: `File f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null)+"/F&H");` That should be: `File f = getExternalFilesDir("F&H");`

Comment: @blackapps i added toast message and it shows toast message at the end of try block there are no errors from try block and i used file3 instead of creating new instance and i also checked logcat for that every thing runs perfectly but backup still creating with size of 0 B. if i misunderstood your point of view pls explain me i am not good with this new methods

Comment: Please adapt your code as suggested. After that we look further.

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);` What do you have in mind with that action? I only realise now that you do not use ACTION_VIEW. What should happen? All that code does not make sense.

Comment: @blackapps i read somewhere in documentation that for creation of document we need to use action_create_document, and here i want to create backup of my db file in external storage

Comment: @blackapps i have made changes as you suggested and edited question

Comment: You create your backup already in that try block. So the rest is not needed. And you implemented my suggestions very sluggy. Bad work. My god... what have you done! Remove all code starting with ACTION_CRERATE DOCUMENT. You did nothing i asked for. File file3 is your backup file of course.

Comment: @blackapps sorry i am newbie i don't know some of the things. i already created my backup but it stores in data directory and it'll be not feasible for user to go find backup in data dir and with new policy i cannot directly copy paste my db file to external storage so, i want to know proper method to create copy of db file which is present in data dir, with documentation i figured out something like this but it is not right can you pls suggest me proper way to do this thing

Comment: `but it stores in data directory ` No dont talk that way. You store in a subdirectory of getExternalFilesDir(). Indeed the user then has no access with other apps. Store you file in the public Documents directory instead then the user has access using the FIles app for instance.

Comment: Or only use Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT to let the user choose a place for the backup and then write the backup in onActivityResult. You code now does not make sense as stated before.

Comment: @blackapps that's the thing i want to know you said that write backup in onActivityResult but i didn't know i have to do that that's why i asked question and there are no other great documentation which i can refer, btw thanks for telling me about onActivityResult now i can backup it successfully. THANKS

Comment: @blackapps and i have to copy my file to data dir because on target sdk 30 they are not giving direct access with root-path

Comment: If you use ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT you have nothing to do with what you wrongfully call data dir(see my earlier comment). The user can only choose a public directory on root of external storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, start activity for result

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
i.setType("application/x-sqlite3");
startActivityForResult(i, BACKUP_CODE);
```

after this it will create file with size of 0 B so we have to write backup in onActivityResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == BACKUP_CODE) {
        try {
            assert data != null;
            FileOutputStream stream = (FileOutputStream) getContentResolver().openOutputStream(data.getData());
            Files.copy(Paths.get(getDatabasePath(DATABASE).toPath()), stream);
            Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            stream.close(); ///very important
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error occurred in backup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

it'll successfully creates backup. It worked for me.

Comment: Still no toast in catch block. Inform the user!

Comment: `after this it will create file with size of 0 B` No. There will be no file created. Or better said: do not create a file somewhere yoursrlf first as you dint know where the user will create the file. And it makes no sense to use a FileProvider there. Remove all that irrelevant code and flags.

Comment: @blackapps gotcha i read one stackoverflow answer and that guy said that these flags are important, and today i searched for lot of answers so it became mess with unnecessary fileProvider and flags but now i understood it properly